# How to remove delimiting characters in loadfile?

Tags: regex, delimiter

Is there a way to write a regex expression that removes 2 delimiting characters "þ" from every line that contains 48 of these characters?

I tried manually removing them, but it takes too long. Then I tried a troubled regex expression: `s/(^(?:.*?þ){46}.*?)þþ(.*)/$1$2/g`, but it failed catastrophically.

Comment: catastrophically? please elaborate. (it aparently works in regex101)

Comment: Add proper tags to indicate where you're using this regex. Also, include example of an input line that you have.

Comment: @PA. Actually [it doesn't](https://regex101.com/r/b0bWJi/1).

Comment: your regex101 removes the 2 delimiting characters þþ in the 48 þ sequence. As stated by the OP and the regex101 demostrates with the appropiate input of 48 char sequence (https://regex101.com/r/b0bWJi/1). More input examples from OP and expected output are needed

Answer (score 1):

You might use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) for the first part matching any character except for `þ` instead of a non greedy dot.

```
^((?:[^þ]*þ){46}).*?þþ(.*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:[^þ]*þ){46})` Repeat 46 times matching character except `þ` followed by matching `þ`
- `.*?þþ` Match as few as possible characters till the first occurrence of `þþ`
- `(.*)` Capture **group 2**, match the rest of the line(s)

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ePlHPi/1).